# Django Url not matching Page no found

Tags: django, django-urls

i have a url that is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/profiles/?profile=17320
```

I have this line define in my urls.py file.

```
url(r'^profiles/(?P<profile>\d+)/$', views.display_profile),
```

and on running, and hitting the above url, it didn't open the page, infact display all available urls list. and also `Page not found (404)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url matches something similar to this

```
127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/542/
```

if you want to use the profile id as a GET parameter instead change your urls to match

```
url(r'^profiles/$', views.display_profile),
```

And inside your view function or inside a class based view inside the `get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` method get your parameter using

```
profile_id = request.GET.get('profile', None)      # where None is the value to use
                                                   # if profile does not exist
```

I hope this helps

**I wrote another answer earlier answering your exact same question**

[How to access url part in python django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661986/how-to-access-url-part-in-python-django/29662679#29662679)

Comment: well on `127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/` the view loads ,but when i run this url `127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/542/` it didn't work and says 404 error.

Comment: What are the available urls that the 404 debug page displays?

Answer (score 3):

your regexp matches

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/17320
```

not

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/profiles/?profile=17320
```

so should be fixed. Also get params (like ?profile=..) are not captured in django urls.

Comment: then how to do this in django

Comment: if you want to pass param in query string and captured them in code, use request.GET.get("param_name")

Comment: @MTaqi, map your view to /users/profiles/ url and get 'profile' parameter from GET dict in request.

Answer (score 1):

Man there is difference in query string and url part as the param.
What you are doing is query string, and you have set up your url pattern for part of the url as param.
So your url should be like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/profiles/17320/`

Read more at [URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/)